# How to create a zoom effect with function call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code in which when user clicks a `link` named `zoom` the an `alert with a zoom effect` is shown to user..

I want the `same to happen` when i `click a button` ...

when i try it to button click its not working.

How to achieve this?How to correct the code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css'>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    /* text-based popup styling */
    
    .white-popup {
      position: relative;
      background: #FFF;
      padding: 25px;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /* 

====== Zoom effect ======

*/
    
    .mfp-zoom-in {
      /* start state */
      /* animate in */
      /* animate out */
    }
    
    .mfp-zoom-in .mfp-with-anim {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    
    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-bg {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    
    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-ready .mfp-with-anim {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    
    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    
    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-removing .mfp-with-anim {
      transform: scale(0.8);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="links">
    <div class id="inline-popups">
      <a href="#test-popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">Zoom</a>
      <button onClick="#test-popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">test</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Popup itself -->
  <div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide">Game completed sucessfull</div>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: <button onClick="#test-popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">test</button> will not work. YOu have to write some jQuery code to pop the div up and give the effect.

does your index.js file has functionalities related to Zoom. if so, please share

Comment: @ratheesh no it does not have functionalities related to zoom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```js
var theControl = $("#test-popup");
            $('#clickMe').magnificPopup({
                items: {
                    src: theControl,
                },
                type: 'inline',
                mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom', // this class is for CSS animation below
                zoom: {
                    enabled: true, // By default it's false, so don't forget to enable it

                    duration: 300, // duration of the effect, in milliseconds
                    easing: 'ease-in-out', // CSS transition easing function

                    // The "opener" function should return the element from which popup will be zoomed in
                    // and to which popup will be scaled down
                    // By defailt it looks for an image tag:
                   
                }
            });
```

```css
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css'>
    <style>
                html,
                body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 10px;
                    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                }
                /* text-based popup styling */

                .white-popup {
                    position: relative;
                    background: #FFF;
                    padding: 25px;
                    width: auto;
                    max-width: 400px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                /*

        ====== Zoom effect ======

        */

                .mfp-zoom-in {
                    /* start state */
                    /* animate in */
                    /* animate out */
                }

                    .mfp-zoom-in .mfp-with-anim {
                        opacity: 0;
                        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                        transform: scale(0.8);
                    }

                    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-bg {
                        opacity: 0;
                        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
                    }

                    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-ready .mfp-with-anim {
                        opacity: 1;
                        transform: scale(1);
                    }

                    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
                        opacity: 0.8;
                    }

                    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-removing .mfp-with-anim {
                        transform: scale(0.8);
                        opacity: 0;
                    }

                    .mfp-zoom-in.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
                        opacity: 0;
                    }
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
 
<button id="clickMe" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">test</button>
  <div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide">Game completed sucessfully</div>
```

Comment: Change the mainClass in the jQuery to    
mainClass: 'mfp-zoom-in mfp-with-anim',

You can give the styles accordingily

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function that the `onclick` attribute will trigger. In that function, you can do the zoom logic that you prefer.

```
 <button onclick="zoomLogic" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">test</button>
```

Inside your script tag or in your script:

```
function zoomLogic() {
  //Grab the element you wish the zoom effect to take place and do your logic
}
```